# How to convert this list into a nested list in python

Tags: python, dijkstra

I have this list

```
['BUD', 'CDG', 'DEL', 'DOH', 'DSM,ORD', 'EWR,HND', 'EWR,HND,ICN', 'EWR,HND,JFK', 'EWR,HND,JFK,LGA', 'EWR,HND,JFK,LGA', 'EWY,LHR', 'EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM', 'EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI', 'EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI,LGA', 'EWY,LHR,SFO,SAN', 'HND,ICN', 'ICN', 'ICN,JFK', 'ICN,JFK,LGA', 'ICN,JFK,LGA', 'LGA', 'LGA', 'LHR,SFO', 'LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD', 'LHR,SFO,SAN', 'LHR,SFO,SAN,EWY', 'ORD,BGI', 'SAN', 'SAN,EWY,LHR', 'SAN,EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM', 'SAN,EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI', 'SAN,EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI,LGA', 'SAN,EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI,LGA', 'SFO,DSM', 'SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI', 'SFO,SAN', 'SFO,SAN,EWY,LHR', 'SIN,CDG,BUD', 'TLV,DEL,DOH']
```

how do I make it so that this whole list becomes a nested list, like this

```
[['BUD'][ 'CDG'][ 'DEL'][ 'EWR','HND','ICN']]
```

I am doing this so that I can sort the above list efficiently

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension for that :

```
myList = ['BUD', 'CDG', 'DEL', 'DOH', 'DSM,ORD', 'EWR,HND', 'EWR,HND,ICN',
        'EWR,HND,JFK', 'EWR,HND,JFK,LGA', 'EWR,HND,JFK,LGA', 'EWY,LHR',
        'EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM', 'EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI', 'EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI,LGA']

result = [el.split(',') for el in myList]

print(result)
```

output:

```
[['BUD'], ['CDG'], ['DEL'], ['DOH'], ['DSM', 'ORD'], ['EWR', 'HND'], ['EWR', 'HND', 'ICN'], ['EWR', 'HND', 'JFK'], ['EWR', 'HND', 'JFK', 'LGA'], ['EWR', 'HND', 'JFK', 'LGA'], ['EWY', 'LHR'], ['EWY', 'LHR', 'SFO', 'DSM'], ['EWY', 'LHR', 'SFO', 'DSM', 'ORD', 'BGI'], ['EWY', 'LHR', 'SFO', 'DSM', 'ORD', 'BGI', 'LGA']]
```

Answer (score 0):

This group each element in order they appear.

`new_list = [data_list[i:i+1] for i in range(0, len(data_list), 1)]`
you can change integar value like if you want to group in form of 5 elements, replace 1 with 5.
.

Answer (score 0):

```
li = ['BUD', 'CDG', 'DEL', 'DOH', 'DSM,ORD', 'EWR,HND', 'EWR,HND,ICN', 'EWR,HND,JFK', 'EWR,HND,JFK,LGA', 'EWR,HND,JFK,LGA', 'EWY,LHR', 'EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM', 'EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI', 'EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI,LGA', 'EWY,LHR,SFO,SAN', 'HND,ICN', 'ICN', 'ICN,JFK', 'ICN,JFK,LGA', 'ICN,JFK,LGA', 'LGA', 'LGA', 'LHR,SFO', 'LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD', 'LHR,SFO,SAN', 'LHR,SFO,SAN,EWY', 'ORD,BGI', 'SAN', 'SAN,EWY,LHR', 'SAN,EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM', 'SAN,EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI', 'SAN,EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI,LGA', 'SAN,EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI,LGA', 'SFO,DSM', 'SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI', 'SFO,SAN', 'SFO,SAN,EWY,LHR', 'SIN,CDG,BUD', 'TLV,DEL,DOH']

op = list(map(lambda x: x.split(','), li))
print(op)
```

Output:

```
[['BUD'], ['CDG'], ['DEL'], ['DOH'], ['DSM', 'ORD'], ['EWR', 'HND'], ['EWR', 'HND', 'ICN'], ['EWR', 'HND', 'JFK'], ['EWR', 'HND', 'JFK', 'LGA'], ['EWR', 'HND', 'JFK', 'LGA'], ['EWY', 'LHR'], ['EWY', 'LHR', 'SFO', 'DSM'], ['EWY', 'LHR', 'SFO', 'DSM', 'ORD', 'BGI'], ['EWY', 'LHR', 'SFO', 'DSM', 'ORD', 'BGI', 'LGA'], ['EWY', 'LHR', 'SFO', 'SAN'], ['HND', 'ICN'], ['ICN'], ['ICN', 'JFK'], ['ICN', 'JFK', 'LGA'], ['ICN', 'JFK', 'LGA'], ['LGA'], ['LGA'], ['LHR', 'SFO'], ['LHR', 'SFO', 'DSM', 'ORD'], ['LHR', 'SFO', 'SAN'], ['LHR', 'SFO', 'SAN', 'EWY'], ['ORD', 'BGI'], ['SAN'], ['SAN', 'EWY', 'LHR'], ['SAN', 'EWY', 'LHR', 'SFO', 'DSM'], ['SAN', 'EWY', 'LHR', 'SFO', 'DSM', 'ORD', 'BGI'], ['SAN', 'EWY', 'LHR', 'SFO', 'DSM', 'ORD', 'BGI', 'LGA'], ['SAN', 'EWY', 'LHR', 'SFO', 'DSM', 'ORD', 'BGI', 'LGA'], ['SFO', 'DSM'], ['SFO', 'DSM', 'ORD', 'BGI'], ['SFO', 'SAN'], ['SFO', 'SAN', 'EWY', 'LHR'], ['SIN', 'CDG', 'BUD'], ['TLV', 'DEL', 'DOH']]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
myList = ['BUD', 'CDG', 'DEL', 'DOH', 'DSM,ORD', 'EWR,HND', 'EWR,HND,ICN',
        'EWR,HND,JFK', 'EWR,HND,JFK,LGA', 'EWR,HND,JFK,LGA', 'EWY,LHR',
        'EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM', 'EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI', 'EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI,LGA']

nested_list = [[element] for element in myList]
```

output :

```
[['BUD'], ['CDG'], ['DEL'], ['DOH'], ['DSM,ORD'], ['EWR,HND'], ['EWR,HND,ICN'], ['EWR,HND,JFK'], ['EWR,HND,JFK,LGA'], ['EWR,HND,JFK,LGA'], ['EWY,LHR'], ['EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM'], ['EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI'], ['EWY,LHR,SFO,DSM,ORD,BGI,LGA']]
```

Comment: This is not the expected output.